# How can I delete an attribute from each entry in an array?

Tags: python

I have created an Array with each element populated with a json(dict) entry I've gathered from a dynamodb.

I want to remove one of the top level attributes in each entry. I think the issue im facing is the Value is a list, but I'm not too sure.

Ive tried several methods using loops and slices but nothing seems to be working for me.

Array example:

```
[
    {
        "Item": {
            "id": "uuid",
            "event": {
                "A": "1",
                "B": "2"            
            }
        },
        "ResponseMetadata": {
            "A": "1",
            "B": {
                "1": "A",
                "2": "B"
                },
            "C": "2"
        }
    },
    {
        "Item": {
            "id": "uuid",
            "event": {
                "A": "1",
                "B": "2"
            }
        },
        "ResponseMetadata": {
            "A": "1",
            "B": {
                "1": "A",
                "2": "B"
                },
            "C": "2"
        }
    }
]
```

Here is a loop I tried:

```
def format_result(result):
    i = 0
    for i in result:
        del i['ResponseMetadata']
        i += 1
    return result
```

Error I got was: 
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item deletion

Also tried i.pop() which gave the error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it in the end:

```
def extract_events_to_array(elist):
    events_list = [get_user_event(event_id) for event_id in elist[:10]]
    return format_result(events_list)


def get_user_event(eventid):
    response = event_table.get_item(
        Key={"eventId": eventid}
    )
    return response


def format_result(events_list):
    for event in events_list:
        del event['ResponseMetadata']
    return events_list
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you want is such thing. `result` is list, the items of list are dict.

```
def format_result(result):
    for item in result:
        item.pop('ResponseMetadata', None)
```

Comment: This gives 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'